# Where on Stack Exchange should I ask about how to find a book on Amazon?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I looked at an interesting math book (an analysis book) on Amazon's website a while ago but I don't remember what it was at all. I remember some details from reviews of the book though. A reviewer commented that they finally understood Green's Functions because of the book in particular because of some insight it gave about the non-commutativity of certain aspects of integrals involving dirac delta functions. Where on Stack Exchange should I ask if anyone knows which book I am talking about?

Comment: Have you googled with 'site:amazon.com'?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Amazon.com+Green%27s+Functions++non-commutativity+aspects+of+integrals++dirac+delta+functions - finds a few, but which review matches your description is another matter.

Answer (score 7):

- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has a [[reference-request]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag, which seems like the best fit to me.
- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic) also has a [[reference-request]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag. MathOverflow only deals with research-level math though (unlike Mathematics, which deals with math at any level).
- [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) also has a [[reference-request]](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag, consider it if you are asking this question in the context of mathematics education.

Answer (score 5):

On [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) you might ask about

1. how to use amazon.com search features
2. how to use a specific search engine (i.e. Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo, etc.) to search content from amazon.com
3. how to use specialized book search engines (i.e books.google.com,  worlcat.org, ...) to search for books

Some related questions from Web Apps

- [How to search for words in Amazon reviews?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19332/88163)
- [Advanced Power Search & Filter of Amazon product data & description beyond Books?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84964/88163)
- [Is there a way to see all Amazon reviews across its international sites?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87953/88163)